# Rails model instance variable not declared in the model class

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just created a model with the following command

```
rails generate model temp name:string description:string
```

I opened `temp.rb` but it does not contain any declaration for the members.

I am also confused the way instance variable are used in ruby. I see many code snippets where it just uses instance variable by @instance_var in methods. isn't instance variable declaration required in ruby?, that way If I have 15 methods and each of them set new instance variable then there is not a single location where all the instance variable can be found like we do in java where we declare all the variables usually at the beginning of class with scope(private, protected, public etc) Here's and example of code

```
class Hello

  def initialize
    @instanceHello = "welcomeBack"
  end

  def printHello

    print @instanceHello
  end
end
```

Comment: No, instance variable declaration is not required in Ruby. Instance variables spring into existence the first time they're used, regardless of *where* they're used. This is both good and bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a model, it isn't `class Hello`; it should be `class Hello < ActiveRecord::Base`. And so it inherits a lot of functionality.

The members aren't defined in the model, rather they are defined in a migration, as you did `rails generate model temp name:string description:string`. If you have a model named `temp`, then there should be a table named `temps` in the database, and that table should actually contain all those members.

The second thing you have asked about the instance variables in Ruby. And yes, it is true that there is no single place where the instance variables  are accumulated; rather they are scattered across different methods to which they belong to; and I think it increases readability.

As far as your example is concerned, you can do something like:

```
class Hello
  attr_accessor :instanceHello
  def initialize
    @instanceHello = "welcomeBack"
    # self.instanceHello also works here
  end

  def printHello
    p @instanceHello # print doesn't work in Ruby. p or puts does the job.
    # self.instanceHello also works here
  end
end
```

Comment: I added code of Hello class to show instance variable declaration in class, it is not related to model. Thanks

Comment: I tried it out, it wasn't printing the given string or variable. Please guide me.